# Exporting FileAttachment using Acumatica WebService

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to get activities for cases from different instance with all File Attachments and Notes attached to the activities. I have tried with different ways, but unfortunately none of them has worked. Can anyone please suggest what is the best way to get all file attachments and notes for the Case Activities using Acumatica WebService.

Here is the code which I tried--

```html
SP203010WS.Content content = context.GetSchema();
export = context.Export
(
 new SP203010WS.Command[]
 {
  new SP203010WS.Value
  {
   LinkedCommand = content.Case.CaseID,
   Value = currentCaseNo
  },

  content.Activities.Type,
  content.Activities.Summary,
  new SP203010WS.Field { FieldName="Body", ObjectName="Activities"},
  content.Activities.StartDate,
  content.Activities.CreatedBy,
  new SP203010WS.Field { FieldName="NoteID", ObjectName="Activities"},
  content.Activities.CreatedAt,
  new SP203010WS.Field
  {
   FieldName = content.Activities.ServiceCommands.Attachment.FieldName,
   Value = content.Activities.ServiceCommands.Attachment.Value,
   LinkedCommand = content.Activities.ServiceCommands.Attachment
  },
  new SP203010WS.Attachment
  {
   FieldName = content.Activities.ServiceCommands.Attachment.FieldName,
   Value = content.Activities.ServiceCommands.Attachment.Value
  },
  new SP203010WS.Value
  {
   FieldName = content.Activities.ServiceCommands.Attachment.FieldName,
   Value = content.Activities.ServiceCommands.Attachment.Value,
   LinkedCommand = content.Activities.ServiceCommands.Attachment
  },
 },
 new SP203010WS.Filter[]
 {
  new SP203010WS.Filter
  {
   Field = content.Activities.StartDate,
   Condition = SP203010WS.FilterCondition.Greater,
   Value = maxStartDate
  }
 },
 0, true, true
);
```

Comment: Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation for I200 (screen-based Web Services) pages 75-76.   First, you have to get the list of file names, and then loop through each one to get the actual attachments.